# GitLab email setup: sending via another mail server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, smtp, gitlab

By default gitlab has the next configuration in `gitlab.yml` :

```
email:
  from: notify@gitlabhq.com
  host: gitlabhq.com
```

but, I need to specify other variables (host, port, user, password, etc) to use another mail server.

How I do that?

Comment: I am looking for the same solution. Please let me know if you have found any better way

Comment: It is not possible for you to install a simple smtp relay on the host running gitlab ? You will then be able to configure it to relay mails using your authenticated mail server

Comment: Look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201090/gitlab-email-notifications-not-sending/16690884#16690884
------

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This confused me too.  But to change the mail setting you edit them in config/environments/production.rb  Just add a config.action_mailer.smtp_settings like a regular rails app.

Answer (score 40):

Now it is totally different in Gitlab 5.2+.

It is in "/home/git/gitlab/config/initializers/smtp_settings.rb.sample" and we just need to follow the instructions in that.

Comment: This is right. Note that the default installation will not have smtp_settings.rb.sample. But you can get it from github

Comment: and need to config postfix?

Comment: in version 6.3.1 the file has been moved to /home/git/gitlab/config/initializers/smtp_settings.rb.sample

Comment: When I try to copy settings I get an exception: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684035/gitlab-smtp-config-exception

Answer (score 30):

**Note**: This method was useful for older versions of Gitlab. [See the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16706460/1165132) of Girish for newer versions.

---

At the end of config/environments/production.rb you can add something like this:

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => 'yourserver.com',
      :port => 25,
      :domain => 'gitlab.yourserver.com',
      :authentication => :plain,
      :user_name => 'gitlab@yourserver.com',
      :password => 'yourPassword',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Refer to the ActionMailer documentation for a more detailed description of possible configurations: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html

**Note**: You may have to edit the file again after a Gitlab update

Comment: note: `:authentication => :login` or `:cram_md5` may be what's needed, also `:enable_starttls_auto => false` should be used when tls/ssl isn't being used on your mail server (typically when the port is 25 as above.)

Comment: Good answer. This works but it is a cleaner option the suggested one by Girish KG. If you modify the production.rb file, you can find problems upgrading gitlab by git and you will need to handle some repository conflicts before get the upgrade succesfully.

Answer (score 7):

For Gitlab > 7 omnibus, edit `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` as below and run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.server"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 465
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "smtp user"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "smtp password"
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "example.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'none'
```

Source: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/smtp.md

Answer (score 5):

The `email:host:` configuration in `gitlab.yml` isn't actually for the mail server/SMTP host. It's used to construct the links to your Gitlab host in the email. We call our gitlab server 'gitlab.local' (and have a DNS entry for it), so our configuration says `host: gitlab.local`.

This way, when users receive an email from Gitlab, the links will work, instead of linking to `http://localhost/`, as is the default.

There's some redundant configuration in there. For the git clone URLs to be displayed correctly within Gitlab, you also need to configure `web:host:` and `git_host:host:` with the same host name.

```
web:
  host: gitlab.local
  port: 80
  https: false

email:
   host: gitlab.local
   protocol: http

git_host:
   host: gitlab.local
```

If you are using HTTPS, change `web:https:`, `web:port:`, and `email:protocol:`.

Comment: I found this answer useful for my own scenario of setting up proper links in GitLab account invitation emails sent from my GitLab local VM; see a question/answer I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589361/how-to-change-the-host-ip-sent-in-emails-to-new-gitlab-users-to-a-publicly-visib

Answer (score 3):

This is my entries at the end in /config/environment/production.rb and that is working for me.

---

Comment out sendmail options and use external SMTP relays

---

```
  # #config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail ## Comment out this

  # Defaults to:

  # # config.action_mailer.sendmail_settings = {

  # #   :location => '/usr/sbin/sendmail',

  # #   :arguments => '-i -t'

  # # }

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  # # SMTP Settings

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {

      :address => '10.146.10.90', ## My SMTP Relay/Gateway

      :port => 25, ## SMTP Port

      :domain => 'gitlab.example.com', ## My Domain

      :authentication => :plain, ## Let it be plain as it is inside my LAN

      ##:user_name => 'gitlab@yourserver.com', ## This is not required as long as 

      ##:password => 'yourPassword', ## SMTP Gateway allows anonymous relay

      ##:enable_starttls_auto => true ## In LAN

      ##:user_name => '',

      ##:password => '',

      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
end
```

---

Comment: People who downwote, please add a comment saying why they downvoted. So that other people can understand why this author's method won't work / is not the best. Please.

Comment: Is it possible to accomplish this all through the /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file?

Answer (score 0):

*Apparently the location of these settings has changed (a few times) since this question was originally asked. Currently as of 2018-11-02:*

**The settings are in `gitlab.rb` as per the official documentation:**

[image]

https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/smtp.html