# How do I specify the host for links in mail notifications in Gitlab?

Tags: ruby, email, notifications, gitlab

I have gitlab running behind a proxy, gitlab itself running on port 3000 not accessible from outside.

Mail notifications generated by gitlab always contain URLs with port 3000 in them, so where can I configure gitlab to generate links accessible from outside?

I already found 
[gitlab email setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690255/gitlab-email-setup/11690213#11690213)
but I do not have `email:host:` or anything like that in my `gitlab.yml`

I'm running gitlab 5.2.0 right now.

EDIT: I would also appreciate any link to some info about the config options in gitlab.yml...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting is indeed in `gitlab/config/gitlab.yml`, it just isn't that clear anymore (config names and comments changed in gitlab 5.0 I think).

The section `## Web Server Settings` is actually used to generate the links in emails. The only settings referring to emails are `email_from:` and `support_email:` but `host:`, `port:` and `https:` are also used for links in emails.

The actual IP and port settings can be found in `puma.rb` config file which is why I was confident enough to just tinker around with the `gitlab.yml` settings and it worked.

Solution for my problem: just comment the `production:gitlab:port:` setting or change it to your external port.